Probability of X events within a given time period T.
I know the pdf/cdf of an event occuring as a function of time, for concreteness it's roughly exponential distribution but not exactly.
I would like to find out the pdf/cdf of X events occuring within some time period T. Is there a general method that doesn't depend on the type of the original function?


The process begins by considering the rate (λ(t)) at which events occur as a function of time. This rate function is essential for calculating the probability of (X) events occurring within the specified interval ([0, T]).
Step 1: Define the Rate Function
For a given probability density function (pdf) (f(t)), representing the time between events, the rate function (λ(t)) could vary with time. Unlike the constant rate (λ) associated with exponential distributions, this function must be derived from the specific characteristics of your pdf.
Step 2: Calculate Expected Number of Events
The expected number of events (λ) within the interval ([0, T]) is obtained by integrating (λ(t)) over this period:
\begin{equation}
\Lambda = \int_{0}^{T} λ(t) \, dt
\end{equation}
Step 3: Determine the Probability of (X) Events
If the scenario approximated a Poisson process, the probability of exactly (X) events occurring within ([0, T]) would follow the Poisson distribution formula:
\begin{equation}
P(X) = \frac{\Lambda^X e^{-\Lambda}}{X!}
\end{equation}
However, with a non-constant (λ(t)), calculating (P(X)) directly from this formula may not be feasible. Instead, understanding the cumulative impact of (λ(t)) on event occurrences requires more complex approaches, such as simulation or numerical integration, to approximate or calculate (P(X)).
No Universal Closed-Form Solution
Given the deviation from the exponential distribution and the potential variability in (λ(t)), there isn't a one-size-fits-all formula for the pdf or cdf of (X) events occurring within (T). The solution often involves:

Numerical simulation: Generating many instances of the process and tallying the occurrence of (X) events within (T) to approximate (P(X)).
Numerical integration: Leveraging numerical methods to evaluate the integrals that represent the probability density or mass function, especially when a straightforward analytical solution is not available.

Conclusion
The outlined steps provide a conceptual pathway for tackling the problem, grounded in the adaptation of Poisson process principles to fit non-standard timing distributions. Implementing these steps to derive practical solutions typically requires detailed knowledge of the specific rate function (λ(t)) derived from the given pdf or cdf, and often, computational approaches are indispensable for achieving accurate results.

Actually I was trying to reformat this and the whole thing became fuzzy let me try.
